# How to remove all unnecessary semicolons (at end of blocks)?

Tags: java, eclipse

Some of our code written a while have unnecessary semi-colon. I wonder whats the easiest way to remove them. For example, the last semi-colon in the following

```
 if(i == 2)
   {
       System.out.println("if statement");
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println("else statement");
   };
```

Comment: If they are all next to a close bracket you could do a Find & Replace searching for "};" and replacing them with "}"

Comment: @eazimmerman: That will break assignments using anonymous inner classes, of course...

Comment: Leave it and clean it up as you fix other bugs. It doesn't hurt anything, so why bother?

Comment: @eazimmerman Be careful with that, there are plenty of valid situations which require a `;` following a `}` - inline array initializers, anonymous inner classes, etc...

Comment: @JonSkeet and Beau: good points, but of course, the very fact that this _would_ break valid occurrences of `};` could be used to sunxin8086's advantage: do the find & replace (after making sure your code is up-to-date) and _see what breaks_ - fixing those errors afterwards may (depending on how many errors you get, of course) turn out to be simpler than tracking down _all_ occurrences. Eclipse's synchronise view should help you track down which changes have also become errors before you commit. If it's too much, simply revert to the latest version from your code repository.

Answer (score 7):

You can *find* them easily enough by going into the Java Compiler / Error and Warnings preferences, then under "Potential Programming Problems" change "Empty Statements" to warning or error. Then it'll just be a matter of going through them. There may be a way of automating it, but I wouldn't bother unless there are loads :)

Comment: there are plenty of them. The reason we are doing this to clean up our code base to conform our code standard more. having them highlighted are definitely helpful, but if we can auto remove them all together, it will be even great.

Comment: @sunxin8086: Unfortunately I don't know of any way of doing that :(

Answer (score 5):

It is probably too late for you but, you can Analyze your code with Intellij IDEA using the Inspection "Unnecessary semi-colon" then after it has found them all you can apply the Fix.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp

Eclipse can also do this too but it suffers from a bug that doesn't allow you to apply the Quick Fix in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

As the above said, by typing ctrl + f and searching for }; and replacing it with } would work great, but could break the code.

They are not necessary to be removed, as it is just the equivalent of:

```
if(true){
  //...
}
/*Empty Line*/;
```

It won't effect the code in any way, but is best to remove them just for preference.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late for you but this could help others:

**CTRL + F**

write what you want to delete in your case **;** and then:

**CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + J**

This will select all the matches for your search in that file.

Then you just have to delete DELETE

Comment: That's probably going to delete a bunch of semicolons that shouldn't be deleted.